# Google play console show me java.lang.IllegalStateException error

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app and when I check crash reports in google play console, it shows me the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3280)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1690)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6592)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:769)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1520)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1476)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:644)
  at com.evernote.android.job.WakeLockUtil.startWakefulService (WakeLockUtil.java:95)
  at com.evernote.android.job.JobRescheduleService.startService (JobRescheduleService.java:24)
  at com.evernote.android.job.JobManager.<init> (JobManager.java:191)
  at com.evernote.android.job.JobManager.create (JobManager.java:114)
  at com.evernote.android.job.JobBootReceiver.onReceive (JobBootReceiver.java:49)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3273)
```

There is no info in what point of my app is crashing. After some research, it seems that it can be something about services, but I'm not using any. I just have some DoInBackground tasks, but I cannont reproduce it, I even know where to search.

Just for info, all the errors I see are from 8.0 version and above

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.cloudinary', name: 'cloudinary-android', version: '1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    compile 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: On GitHub I found same thread which says that you have to search another source for your player.  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/issues/163

Comment: @Abhinav that's unfortunately an entirely different error. -- The error here comes from using (an outdated version of) the https://github.com/evernote/android-job library which after device boots receives a boot completed broadcast and then fails to start an internal service. I'd try whether upgrading to a more recent version of the library fixes this.

Comment: @zapl, I'm not using this library, but I'm using AsyncTask, has the error relation with it?

Comment: Not related to `AsyncTask`. Either you or something you use uses that library. `com.evernote.android.job...` can't appear in your app stacktrace otherwise. run e.g. `gradlew.bat :app:dependencies --configuration releaseRuntimeClasspath` or in android studio in the "gradle" tab under `:app`>`Tasks`>`help`>`dependencies` to see the dependency graph of your app

Comment: Might help if you include your android manifest file and build.gradle, if there's a service it will show up in the manifest and if you're using a third party component, like firebase, which has a service that will show up in the build.gradle file.  Probably you didn't initialize a third party component correctly and it is crashing.

Comment: In fact, I'm using firebase and other stuff, maybe i'm using some old version of something? I have added my dependencies in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an evernote issue, based on the stacktrace:

```
com.evernote.android.job.JobBootReceiver.onReceive
```

Might check to make sure you're using the latest version of their dependencies in your build.gradle file.

Looks like this issue:

https://github.com/evernote/android-job/issues/254

Check you setup, maybe not initializing something correctly for evernote.